# Running the Drop node from a launch file

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-kinetic, topic-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to run the drop node from topic_tools package with others nodes in a launch file, how can i do this?

i saw this example:

```
<node name="listener1" pkg="rospy_tutorials" type="listener.py" args="--test" respawn="true" />
```

but i don't know what 'name' and 'type' should be.

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322992/running-the-drop-node-from-a-launch-file/) by [yakovkor](https://answers.ros.org/users/38996/yakovkor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is almost a duplicate of #q40304, but that is with `throttle` instead of `drop`.

The idea is similar though:

```
<launch>
  <node name="foo_dropper" type="drop" pkg="topic_tools" args="<intopic> <X> <Y> [outtopic]" />
</launch>
```

Where you'd replace `<intopic> <X> <Y> [outtopic]` with the appropriate values of course.

Refer to the [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/drop) for more information on the usage and command line arguments of `drop`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yakovkor](https://answers.ros.org/users/38996/yakovkor/) on 2019-05-12**:
Hi, i'll try this tomorrow. thanks!